# Pagina pierde estilos al sumar "1" en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo un problema al querer sumar "1" a una variable en PHP me distorsiona los estilos CSS a mi pagina.

Les explico, la pagina normal se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando sumo "1" se pone asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php
//Crear Variables para conexion Noticias Principales
$host = "localhost";
$user = "kautivai_EditorDeNoticias";
$pw = "0927410654marvin";
$dataBase1 = "kautivai_DatosDeNoticias";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $dataBase1) or die("Problemas al conectar con base de datos 'kautivai_DatosDeNoticias'");

$obtener_filas = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1");
$numero_de_fila = mysqli_num_rows($obtener_filas); //Debo sumar "1" para obtener la ultima fila.. asi: $numero_de_fila = mysqli_num_rows($obtener_filas) + 1;
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

    // Ejecutas las consulta 
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1 WHERE ID = '$numero_de_fila'") or die("Error al realizar consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

    while($final = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
?>

<div id="contenedorHeader">
<header>
    <div id="centrado">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="imagenes/kautivaLogo.jpg" id="logo2"></a>
        <img src="imagenes/menu.png" id="menuIcon">
        <ul>
            <a><li>INICIO</li></a>
            <a href="deportes.html"><li>DEPORTES</li></a>
            <a href="edicion.html"><li>VIDEOS</li></a>
            <a href="noticia.php"><li>VIRALES</li></a>
            <a href="contacto.html"><li>CONTACTO</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
</div>

        <ul id="menu2">
            <a href="index.html"><li>INICIO</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>DEPORTES</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>VIDEOS</li></a>
            <a href="noticia.html"><li>VIRALES</li></a>
            <a href="contacto.php"><li>CONTACTO</li></a>
        </ul>

        <div id="CajaRedesPC">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/KautivaOficial/"><div class="redesBox"><img src="imagenes/fdefacebook.png" class="redes"></div></a>
            <a><div class="redesBox"><img src="imagenes/birdTwitter.png" class="redes"></div></a>
            <a><div class="redesBox"><img src="imagenes/google.png" class="redes"></div></a>
            <a><div class="redesBox"><img src="imagenes/linkedin.png" class="redes"></div></a>
            <a><div class="redesBox"><img src="imagenes/pinterest.png" class="redes"></div></a>
        </div>

<div id="general" >
    <h1 class="indicadores">Destacados de hoy</h1>

    <hr class="barrasHorizontales" size="3px" color="#1A354C" width="100%" noshade="noshade" style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; opacity: 1;">

    <!--================================================ Bloque Principal ===============================================-->
    <section id="general2">
        <article id="articleIzquierdo">
            <div id="NOTBIG1">
                <div id="fotoB1"><? echo '<img src="'.$final['RutaImagen'].'" class="PORTADAS1">'; ?></div>

                <h3 id="Etiqueta1" style="color: #20a2e3; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><?php echo $final['Etiqueta']; ?></h3>

                <hr size="1px" width="100%" noshade="noshade" style="margin: 10px auto; opacity: 0.3;">

                <h1 class="titulosMain" id="Titulo1"><?php echo $final['Titulo']; ?></h1>
                <h1 class="Subtitulos" id="Subtitulo1"><?php echo $final['Subtitulo']; ?></h1>
                <p style="color: #2E2E2E; font-weight: lighter; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 10px;">Por: <span style="color: #1279a8;"><?php echo $final['Autor']; ?> <span style="color: #2E2E2E;">|</span></span>&nbsp;<span><?php echo $final['Fecha']; ?></span></p>
                <p class="resumenTitulos"><?php echo $final['Texto']; ?></p>
            </div>
<?php
    }//Cierre de while
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Y que sigue después del `while`?

Comment: ¿Puedes por favor compartir todo tu código para poder intentar correrlo localmente?

Comment: Listo, ya puse todo el codigo

Comment: No lo entienden?? Porque siempre que pongo mi codigo, dejan de responder..!

Comment: ¿Tú te has dado cuenta de lo que hace tu código? Al introducir el HTML dentro del `while` te crea una y otra vez ese contenido, de modo que si la consulta tiene 100 registros, o 1,000 o 10,000 tú estás creando el mismo contenido esa cantidad de veces. Eso es lo primero que deberías corregir. Al estar ahora en el móvil se me dificulta ver qué uso das a `$final` dentro del bucle. Lo cierto es que debes generar todo el HTML invariable fuera del bucle y construir dentro del bucle solo aquella parte que sea dinámica.